# How do I connect my Android smartphone using virtual USB to my computer

Tags: android, usb, adb, virtual, wireless

Friends, my phone and my computer are on the same network, I can ping the phone locally but I need to run the command "adb tcpip 5555" without Root.

But I am facing problem that I have no way to connect this phone via USB to my computer, so I need to make a virtual USB connection to my computer so I can activate adb.

Help me to solve this problem please, how can i execute the command "adb tcpip 5555" without Root and without USB wire

I've tried different programs, along the lines of USB Gate, but they don't do the basic task I need them to do.

They will transfer devices that are connected to the phone, and I need to connect the phone itself via virtual USB.

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to connect it because if you want to connect it for testing your app for real device there have a option.

Comment: I am working with Android devices for years but I have not heard of a virtual USB connection. If the Android device is running Android 11+ you can enable wireless adb and pair it with adb on the PC. Otherwise you need a physical USB connection at least once after boot to use adb over IP.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Robert's comment above (about Android 11+).
You don't need `adb root` for most purposes.
Sounds like your computer and/or android may be a virtualized (or cloud-hosted) and you do not have a way to proxy out. If your device is newer (Android 11+), you can use the `Wireless debugging` feature to establish connectivity without ever needing a physical USB connection. See https://source.android.google.cn/docs/automotive/virtualization/tools for mdns based (no physical connectivity dependency) for more info.
Alternatively (in case your local USB connectivity is failing, for whatever reason), there're approaches to resolve that as well (like ADB_LIBUSB=1).